# Proving solution existence and uniqueness of the Helmholtz equation with Robin boundary conditions with complex coefficients

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, helmholtz-equation

I am trying to solve the Helmholtz equation with Robin boundary conditions with complex coefficients and the weak formulation

$$
\iint_\limits\Omega\nabla p_0(x,y)\nabla\left(\overline{v(x,y)}\right)dxdy-\frac{w^2}{c^2}\iint\limits_{\Omega}p_0(x,y)\left(\overline{v(x,y)}\right)dxdy\\
+ik\int\limits_{\partial\Gamma_R}p_0(x,y)\left(\overline{v(x,y)}\right)dx=0, \quad \forall v\in V
$$

but I do not know how can I prove the existence and uniqueness of the solution because the coercitive in the Lax-Milgram theorem is a big problem.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to ask on https://math.stackexchange.com/ and state explicitly the equations you're are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options:

1. Prove the inf-sup condition.
2. Use the Fredholm alternative and the result that says "only the trivial function can satisfy a second-order PDE with zero right hand side, zero Dirichlet condition, and zero normal derivative on the same part of boundary".

The PhD thesis of Prof. Melenk contains a lot of information regarding the Helmholtz equation:

[www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~melenk/publications/diss.ps.gz](http://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~melenk/publications/diss.ps.gz)